# Compiler construction: how return different closures from function?

Tags: compiler-construction, language-agnostic, closures

I write a compiler for a toy language. I my language I want functions to be first-class citizens.
If I understood properly, when compiler sees nested function which uses outer variables, it creates a closure. Closure could be implemented as a class which holds free variables and the function itself.

Now consider the following code:

```
func bar(a:Int, b:Bool) -> (Void -> Int)
  func foo1() -> Int
    return a + 1
  end

  func foo2() -> Int
    return a + 2
  end

  if b then
    return foo1
  else
    return foo2
  end
end
```

Compiler can rewrite this code as:

```
class Foo1
  var a := 0
  func foo1() -> Int
    return self.a + 1
  end
end

class Foo2
  var a := 0
  func foo2() -> Int
    return self.a + 2
  end
end

func bar(a:Int, b:Bool) -> //what is the return type of this function?
  if b then
    var foo1: Foo1
    foo1.a = a
    return foo1
  else
    var foo2: Foo2
    foo2.a = a
    return foo2
  end
end
```

But in this case what the return type of `bar()` will be? Or are closures implemented differently?

Comment: It returns a function reference/pointer.

Comment: I ask you to specify the PL in which the last program with "class" declarations is written.

Comment: @FrankC. Function pointers only contain a function's address - they don't contain any data. So you can't implement closures using just a function pointer.

Comment: @sepp2k I don't disagree with your point but the answers are highly subjective based on implementation bias. There is also ambiguity such that the closed over var `a` has *no* type. I answered the first `type` question on what is returned and it is a function pointer. It is a reasonable implementation (not one I would go with) as shown.

Comment: @FrankC. It is impossible to correctly implement closures with just function pointers. You cannot store any environment information. Consider the case where bar is called several times with different arguments. Using just a function pointer won't be enough to represent the environments of the different closures.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, your compiler would *effectively* generate a common base class for both types.

The real answer depends on what kind of compiler you're actually writing.

Your example is basically a transpiler that generates another (simpler?) OO language, so it would generate a common base class for all block types with the same signature, so a `VoidBlockIntReturn` class, with a single method, `func call() -> Int`. Both your `foo1` and `foo2` would then implement `call()`, and anyone who calls a block would call `call()` on that object.

If your OO language supports proper Smalltalk-style message sending and *duck typing*, you wouldn't even need a base class, just a convention that the method have the same message name (i.e. `call`).

If you actually compiled to assembler, it would be even easier: Assembler doesn't really have data types, or distinguish between data and code. Data is just a bunch of bytes, so is code.

The instructions you run on a piece of data decide as which type those bytes are interpreted. So just like our duck typing approach, as long as the `call` method's instructions are at the same offset into the data (your block), and take the same parameter and return types, these blocks will just be exchangeable as far as an assembler is concerned.

Also, assembly language/machine code can address data relative to code, so you could generate a function that contains data right after its code, in the same memory block, and uses instruction-relative addressing ("PC-relative addressing") to look it up. Then you basically have function pointers that you can pass to anyone who can deal with a function pointer, and they can still capture data.

However, in that case, you would have to make a copy of the entire block (including its code) each time it captures new variable values, and it would be hard to implement proper memory protection, as you'd have executable code and mutable data on the same memory page.

Although one could alleviate some of that by creating a block as an object (or struct) that starts with bytes that are identical to a jump instruction preceded by an instruction that writes a pointer to its data to a register or pushes it on the stack. That way, the actual block code would be shared as a regular function, and the object could be typecast to a function pointer and called by people who know nothing about blocks.

The instructions at its start would then basically call the function, and pass the pointer to the data as a hidden extra parameter.

I actually blogged about how blocks work here, in case you want to read another piece that might help: http://orangejuiceliberationfront.com/what-a-block-really-is/

Answer (score -1):

You choose the result type of the `bar` function depending on the PL in which your compiler generates code (target PL).

For example, make classes `Foo1` and `Foo2` inherit from a class `Foo` or implement an interface `Foo`. In this case, any function must have type `Foo`. `Foo` would be the result type of `bar`. This approach loses type information in the following sense. `Foo` must have a method that applies/calls a function, and that method will take a value of type `Value` and return a value of type `Value` because a value of type `Foo` may be a function of any type. So a generated code will inevitably contain type casts. However, it is not a real issue if the target PL is untyped.

In principle, you can use a more specific type. For example, define a `Func` type constructor with 2 arguments. In this case, any function from `X` to `Y` must have type `Func (X, Y)` in a generated code. `Func (Void, Int)` would be the result type of `bar`. But the type system of the target PL should be sophisticated. I never heard of such an approach.

Answer (score -1):

This is a type-theory issue.

From what you're saying, I understand that your toy language is statically typed. Statically typed languages require you to provide the compiler with explicit types (or enough information to infer the types, as done in Ocaml).
In order to tell your compiler the type of bar, you need to either have the same type for both foor1 and foo2, or add support for union types to your toy language (example: [Ocaml union types](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/data_types_and_matching.html#Variants-qualified-unions-and-enums)).